# DropDownButton Does not show the option that I chose

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-widget, flutter-dropdownbutton

I am using Flutter and are planning to make a dropdownbutton for user to select from. Upon selecting one of the option it will still shows the hint instead of the option that the user chose.

this is the code:

```
DropdownButton<String>(
              isExpanded: true,
              items: <String>['student', 'driver'].map((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: new Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
              hint: new Text ("Select a Role"),
              onChanged: (value) => _role = value,
            ),
```

Thank you in advance for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should like this

```dart
DropdownButton<String>(
              isExpanded: true,
              items: <String>['student', 'driver'].map((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: new Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
              value:_role,
              hint: new Text ("Select a Role"),
              onChanged:  (value) => setState((){
                       _role = value
                   }),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `setState` inside the `onChanged`. You've to assign `_role` to the `value` property of `DropdownButton`.

Here is the [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/794194a7465c876060c47d71f3b3735a?null_safety=true) I've created.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  
  String? _role = 'student';
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      isExpanded: true,
      items: <String>['student', 'driver'].map((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: new Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
      value: _role,
      hint: new Text("Select a Role"),
      onChanged: (value) => setState(() => _role = value),
    );
  }
}
```